# Auto select comboBox item

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I use a `comboBox` with `autocompletemode.append` and `autocompletesource.listitem`properties.

But when I have the `comboBox` in `dropDown` mode and try to type one of elements from list and then try to commit (push <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd> key) the value that is `selected == null`.
When I type one of the value from list without "open" dropdownlist of combobox everything is ok.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: you have to type one letter in the word of list item and then you have to select that item ....

Comment: but i wish enter and tab works as "commit" button

Comment: yes but first you have select the item and then press enter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to replicate your issue.. this works as expected:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedText);
    }
}
```